# How to update value of a column based on sum of same column values of other records in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I apologize if this is a basic question.

I have a table **results** like this :

[image]

I have records for 100s of ids like this.

I want to update all the records which has Type 'ALL' with the sum of Marks of 'Maths' and 'Physics' belonging to same **id** and **date**.

Desired result:

[image]

I am thinking of using UPDATE clause, but not sure how to structure it logically.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to record the ALL data in the table directly, you can just view that data whenever you want by having a query which runs a SUM calculation (grouped by date & id). As a general rule in SQL , you store the raw data, and just calculate the aggregated data when you need it (the only exception is when the scale of that calculation causes performance problems, but that certainly isn't the case here).

Comment: @ADyson I agree with your proposal too.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. But this is one time update to all the records with type 'ALL' that has NULL values instead of sum of all the marks. There has been some mistake in loading the data and the 'ALL' type got NULL instead of desired sum of the individual types. My original requirement is to call the records with Type 'ALL' for each user and list the marks, query : SELECT Marks from results WHERE Type='ALL' . Since it is NULL, I have to do a complex query every time to get aggregate marks. So, I want to update the Type 'ALL' for once and just run a simple query over and over.

Comment: `I have to do a complex query`...the query would not be complex. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8821f9f7ae56f6b1307327c16136b30 . Then you can run that as many times as you like to get the latest marks. You can even store it in a View for ease of use (then you can just `SELECT * FROM \`yourview\`` like it's a table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql multi table update manual page - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

eg

```
drop table if exists t;

CREATE TABLE T(ID INT,SUBJECT VARCHAR(10), MARK INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,'ALL',NULL),(1,'AAA',1),(1,'BBB',2),
(2,'ALL',NULL),(2,'AAA',10),(2,'BBB',20);

UPDATE T 
JOIN
 (SELECT ID,SUM(MARK) MARK FROM T WHERE SUBJECT <> 'ALL' GROUP BY ID) S ON S.ID = T.ID
SET T.MARK = S.MARK
WHERE SUBJECT = 'ALL';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this url: [mySql with rollup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).
It uses the rollup modifier with which you can make the sum grouped by specific rows. Look at the examples given and feel free to ask again.

Comment: This is kind of related, but is still off from what I need. This rollup adds extra columns and not update the existing one. My requirement is to update the existing column value with an aggregation of values of same column for other records.